# NetBeans - New projects do not show up in Projects view

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-7

Just installed Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and OpenJDK (7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4).
I am not able to see any of the created projects. The New project flow goes up to last screen for creating project and just hangs there.

Any possible solutions?

[image: Screenshot of projects view]

Comment: what about when opening the existing projects?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the most recent NetBeans version 8 and Oracle JDK (not the OpenJDK)